# bootstrapped jekyll project fails to load its auto-generated css

Tags: jekyll

I've created a new jekyll project precisely following the simple command sequence at https://jekyllrb.com/. However it seems like the server is not looking for the right `main.css`:

```
GET http://example.com/css/main.css 404 (Not Found)
```

This error in the browser console seems to imply an irrelevant domain for a local project, so I wonder whether [those instructions just mentioned](https://jekyllrb.com/) are not what one should do for bootstrapping and running/testing a jekyll project on your local server. In that case, what is the right procedure for working locally? and is there an automated command for setting a different host name for deploying to a real server?

I am using a fresh install of jekyll 3.2.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Dirty temporary patch ([because of this issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5352)).

In `_config.yml`, set `url: http://matanster.github.io/bloglike` or wathever is your production url.

Create a `config_dev.yml` and add `url: http://127.0.0.1`

Locally, you can serve with :

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml
```